# How do I get the SSL client certificate information from a CherryPy handler?

Tags: ssl, cherrypy

I was able to setup the CherryPy HTTPServer to require an SSL client certificate using the following code:

```
ssl_certificate = os.environ.get("SSL_CERTIFICATE")
ssl_adapter = BuiltinSSLAdapter(
    certificate=ssl_certificate,
    private_key=os.environ["SSL_PRIVATE_KEY"],
    certificate_chain=os.environ.get("SSL_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN")
)
verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ssl_adapter.context.verify_mode = verify_mode
HTTPServer.ssl_adapter = ssl_adapter
```

Now I am trying to get the SSL client certification information from my request handler, but I can't figure how. After reading https://github.com/cherrypy/cheroot/blob/master/cheroot/ssl/builtin.py#L419 it seems that the wsgi environment variables should be populated with SSL_CLIENT* variables. I could not find any method/property from the request objectwould allow me to fetch such information

How can I obtain this variables from a request handler ?

Answer (score 0):

I have learned the answer from a conversation with CherryPy maintainers on Gitter.

An CherryPy request object may contain more attributes than those documented in the API [source](https://tools.ietf.org/doc/python-cherrypy3/api/cherrypy._cprequest.Request-class.html), such attributes are set dynamically once the request object is created as part of the WSGI handling:

https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/_cpwsgi.py#L319

```
...
        request.multithread = self.environ['wsgi.multithread']
        request.multiprocess = self.environ['wsgi.multiprocess']
        request.wsgi_environ = self.environ
...
```

Knowing this, to obtain the WSGI environment which includes the SSL* variables, we just need to access it by importing the request object:

```
import cherrypy.request
...
print(cherrypy.request.wsgi_environ)
...
```